# Spark is writing blank files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For some reason, Spark is writing blank files. Not sure what I've been doing incorrectly.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, DataFrame, DataFrameWriter, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType, BooleanType, ArrayType, IntegerType, TimestampType


    if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('start')
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("testing") \
        .config("spark.ui.enabled", "true") \
        .master("yarn-client") \
        .getOrCreate()


    myschema = StructType([\
                         StructField("field1", TimestampType(), True), \
                         StructField("field2", TimestampType(), True), \
                         StructField("field3", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("field4", StringType(), True), \
                         StructField("field5", StringType(), True), \
                         StructField("field6", IntegerType(), True), \
                         ])

    df = spark.read.load("s3a://bucket/file.csv",\
                 format="csv", \
                 sep=",", \
                 # inferSchema="true", \
                 timestampFormat="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                 header="true",
                 schema=myschema
                )

    print(df.count()) #output is 50

    df.write.csv(path="s3a://bucket/folder",\
                                                                header="true"
                                                                )
```

Output from the `print` statement is 50, which is correct. But the output file on S3 has just a file with headers without any data. Should I be adding another option to the `write` function? I'm not sure why I'm not seeing any data being written

Comment: Those users/questions seem to have output files that have some data. I'm getting just 1 file, which has absolutely no data aside from the header. Even updating the last `write` function to `df.coalesce(1).write.csv(path="s3a://bucket/folder", header="true")` outputs 1 file, which is still blank

Comment: Try `df.show()` and see what's the output.

Comment: Weird, I wasn't able to load anything from the file I was initially trying to use. Read in another file and it all worked out